# Any open-source tool for SAP Hybris app devops automation?

Tags: jenkins, devops, sap-commerce-cloud

We are trying to do automation for the build and deployment of the SAP Hybris application which is using the SAP Cloud studio SDK, can any of you please help us understand if there are any open source tools available which can interact with the SAP Cloud studio SDK or if there are any licensed tools, primarily to implement the DevOps automation for the code quality or test automation aspect.

Comment: hybris word used as a lot of product name by SAP nowadays (commerce, crm, marketting, etc). Can you give exact product name which is you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins CI and CD server is available [since SDK v.5](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/03/02/sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-continuous-delivery-v5-is-available/) to automate Java apps CI/CD pipeline using [SAP S4Hana Archetypes](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes)

Here is [official doc](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline) and [here is manual](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/20/continuous-integration-and-delivery/) for building testing configuration.